# show image in aspect ratio and all image size same height and width

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, image

I createe an image gallery in PHP/MySQL database. How to show image in aspect ratio with same image size ?

This is my css code:

```
img
{
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-out;
  transition: all 2s ease-out;

  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

in this code the ratio of the image is correct, but it shows different size image. I want to show the whole image in:

```
width:150px;
height:200px;
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do all images have the same aspect ratio or differnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

And a parent element with your desired width and height.